# gdb doesn't show symbol from a shared library when another library has the same symbol

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

I am debugging a Linux program, which is linked with two shared libraries (liba.so and libb.so). Each library has the same symbol "Journal" in the same file "main.cpp'. gdb finds and prints only the symbol from one of the libraries.
How can I find and print the symbol from another library?
How can I print all symbols from a specific shared library?

```
(gdb)info var Journal
File ../main.cpp:

SJournalEntry Journal[64];

(gdb) info address Journal

Symbol "Journal" is static storage at address 0x7ffff7febee0.

(gdb) info symbol 0x7ffff7febee0

Journal in section .bss of /usr/lib/liba.so
```

But here is another symbol:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x7ffff7dc7070

Journal in section .bss of /usr/lib/libb.so
```

Answer (score 0):

> gdb finds and prints only the symbol from one of the libraries.

You are probably looking at [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13590#c2).

> How can I find and print the symbol from another library?

I don't think you can (short of running `nm libb.so` and manually relocating the symbol to `libb.so` load address).

Note: under normal symbol resolution rules, and assuming the symbol is global, all references to `Journal` will bind to the same symbol, so the fact that the symbol is also present in another library is irrelevant.

> How can I print all symbols from a specific shared library?

Again I don't believe there is a way in GDB to do that.